# How to access super or parent method from groovy anonymous class?

Tags: groovy

I want to know how we can access a parent method from an overriding child method using an anonymous class. Shown in the example below `cc` was declared as an anonymous class. How do I override the parent method `testMethod1`, yet still have access to the original ones? The keyword `super` doesn't seem to help in my case.

```
abstract class ParentClass {
    def prop1="abc" 
    def testMethod1 () {
        println("testMethod1 in parent");
    }
    def testMethod2 () {
        println("testMethod2 in parent");
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
}

def cc = [
    testMethod1:{
        super.testMethod1(); // Error, why? What is the proper way to call parent method?
        println("testMethod1 in child");
    },
    testMethod2:{
        println("testMethod2 in child");
    }

] as ChildClass;

println("Starting");
println (cc.prop1);
cc.testMethod2();
//cc.testMethod1();
```

The result is:

```
Starting
abc
testMethod2 in child
```

You can try it here:
https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5076402630033408

Comment: I think of this as a case of *just because you can do it, doesn't mean you should do it*... Why not override the methods in `ChildClass`? Or... why need the relationship to the class if that's completely unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

Groovy closure does not support `super` to access members of super class.
See:  https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html

The following code is recommended:

```
abstract class ParentClass {
    def prop1="abc" 
    def testMethod1() {
        println("testMethod1 in parent")
    }
    def testMethod2() {
        println("testMethod2 in parent")
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    def testMethod1() {
        super.testMethod1()
        println("testMethod1 in child")
    }

    def testMethod2() {
       println("testMethod2 in child")
    }
}

cc = new ChildClass()

println("Starting")
println(cc.prop1)
cc.testMethod1()
cc.testMethod2()
```

The output is:

```
Starting
abc
testMethod1 in parent
testMethod1 in child
testMethod2 in child
```

Here is the AIC way:

```
cc = new  ParentClass() {
    def testMethod1() {
        super.testMethod1()
        println("testMethod1 in child")
    }

    def testMethod2() {
       println("testMethod2 in child")
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this can be done using a nomal declaration. I would like to know if there is a way to do it through anonymous class coding style.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, an AIC way was added.